# Shopify Sort cart.items array using Liquid script

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I want to sort the cart.items array in the cart.liquid file. And then I can display the times in the table in my expected order.

```
    {% for item in cart.items sort_by:item.line_price %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12">
      <h1>Your cart</h1>
      <form action="/cart" method="post" id="cartform">
        <table>
        </table>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

But the code doesn't work since I can't use `sort_by:item.line_price` in `for` statement.

How can I sort an array using built-in features?

The other problem is Shopify liquid doesn't support to create an array. if I use my own algorithm to sort the array. But how can I save the output to a new array?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just render your data to a Javascript data structure and then sort it. Use a template in Javascript. Handlebars.js works well for that. There is no built-in sort.

Comment: Good idea, I thought about it before, it will work for cart.liquid page. But it doesn't work for "New Order Notification" because the email template doesn't support JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Shopify has a [sort filter](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/5-output#sort_input_property__nil) for "an array of hashes or drops". You could use it this way:

```
{% assign cart_items = cart.items | sort: "line_price" %}
{% for item in cart_items %}
- {{item.title}} {{item.line_price}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can I use custom field like "item.properties['tags'] contains '[Hardware]'"?

Comment: No I don't think so, from reading the [code](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/c8f38ad9d0afda4d70da24f1e25cc7f577cf4e22/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb#L83), which **might** be used internally for Shopify as well, it seems this syntax isn't supported.

Comment: Also items (line_items) don't have a field `properties`. The product tags are only available from the product (`item.product.tags`).

Comment: item does have a properties field. I can accessitem.properties['tags']. I have fixed this issue by using a string with delimiters to store the index of cart.items. It's very ugly, but it works.